# Hyper Threads, SIPI and Registers

Tags: x86, multicore, hyperthreading

I'm interested to learn more regarding the x86 architecture, and how it implements multi-processing.

Let's say using `cpuid` instruction you can recognize how many logical cores  your processor has, and using some SIPI (Startup Inter Processor Interrupt) you tell core A to start fetching and executing code from some address, and that's basically how you start multi-processing ( as long as the code executing is designed for such architecture of course! )

My questions are the following:

1. Does a SIPI trigger a logical core? if not how logical cores are triggered to execute code
2. Does a logical core have it's own set of registers or, it's just double instruction pointers and the processor has some clever physical way to switch contexts between cores and execute from both the IP's (Given the amount of logical cores per physical are two)
3. Let's say every core needs it's own memory masking hence get's its own MMU, logical cores should have their own MMU right? if not does an operating system manage memory per core while considering the amount of logical cores on a physical one?

I've tried finding documentation about this before, yet found myself stuck with thousands of pages of Intel's documentation, and I'm simply wondering if someone has this knowledge and could shed some light upon my questions and explains what really happens to me

Answer (score 1):

From the programmer's perspective  (which includes the firmware and operating system), *a logical, hyper-threaded core core is just as good as a true, physical one*<sup>1</sup> .

The x86 is much, much more complex than can be put into an answer of reasonable length here. But essentially, a hyper-threaded core duplicates the minimal amount of state required to make it seem as if there's another full core present (basically the registers). It is the actual execution units (instruction decoder, ALU, etc). that are shared between local cores. The core keeps track of which logical core each unit is effectively working for.

Logical CPUs will also have their own CR3 register, the base of the page table hierarchy. However, AFAIK the TLB, L1 cache, and all other components of the MMU (which clearly isn't a distinct entity on x86) are shared between logical cores. A page fault will still be delivered to the appropriate logical CPU.

For more information than you could ever want, you should look at Hennessy and Patterson's book, "Computer Architecture - A Quantitative Approach".

---

1 - This is not entirely true. Consider an OS trying to run two tasks on a 4-core, Hyper-threaded CPU. It would be foolish to schedule those two tasks on logical cores of the same physical core, leaving three other physical cores to sleep, knowing that they won't actually execute concurrently.

Comment: So basically one could say that when scheduling scheduler rises per PHYSICAL core and only then decided which logical core within that physical one should run some program?

Comment: @DrPrItay I'm not entirely sure what you mean. But I would say that when scheduling a task to be run, the scheduler can/should prefer a logical cpu on a physical core with no tasks to a logical cpu on a physical core with busy logical cores.

Comment: Let's go through the following scenario, A timer interrupt has raised to some core. That's per physical core, right? now some IRQ should handle that interrupt and call the scheduler.... right? I'm not sure if it works in the following way, Timed interrupts are used to schedule tasks, but are they raised per physical or logical core? that sounds impossible for me that an interrupt would be raised per logical core. and if they're raised per physical one it means that when scheduling the scheduler decides which tasks shall run on the current physical core it is running... right?

Comment: Again, from the perspective of software, a logical core is the same as a physical one. That means it has its own local APIC as well, so yes, timer interrupts will be delivered to logical cores too. If you don't want interrupts from other devices to be delivered to both logical cores per phys, then don't route the interrupts that way. But you need a timer thread per log. core in order to preempt user code running on that core.